# Make Javascript function argument part of variable

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

I want to merge a argument of a function with a variable
But i don't know how to do that.

```
firstDates = [];

function myFunction(partOne) {
    partOne + Dates.push(someOtherVar); 
}

myFunction(first);
```

I know that this not works, but what would be the right way?

Comment: For starters, decide what your variable names should be, and stick with them.

Comment: How is the first line related to the rest of the code? I'm confused...

Comment: i want to merge variables with arguments in my function

Comment: What is `first`? What is `someOtherVar`? What do you mean by "merge" the variable with the argument? What does this have to do with pushing into an Array?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to do `partOne.push(someOtherVar);`

Comment: Are you trying to join strings to dynamically reference a variable? If so, don't. Describe what you're ultimately after, and you'll be given an appropriate solution.

Comment: i want to make a variable in my function that is one part of my argument. So if i have a argument "first" and in my function a variable named "dates" then i want to make the variable "firstdates"

Comment: @user1386906 and that is bad.  Stick to good coding practices.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not something like this?

```
var dates = {};

function myFunction(partOne) {
   dates[partOne] = [];               // dates["first"] = []
   dates[partOne].push(someOtherVar); // dates["first"].push(someOtherVar)
}

myFunction("first");
```

Otherwise what you are trying to accomplish is an eval type of set up. This is generally a very bad idea.  Don't use dynamically named variables.

Comment: `Dates = [];` should be `var dates = {};`

Comment: @thesystem No, because in that case you would need `Dates.partOne = [];`.  Both methods will work, but I did choose to use arrays because it was closer to OP's test case.  However, it would be beneficial to show future users an Object based method.  If you write it out as an answer, I'll upvote it. EDIT: actually come to think of it, that doesn't work either, but still and Object based approach would be nice.

Comment: Nope, you'd need `dates[partOne] = [];`. An Array *(which you're using)* is an Object. Both will access properties/indices in an identical manner. But using an Array for this is misleading. The proper choice for an unordered list of key/value pairs is an Object.

Comment: ...and then `var` should always be used to make declarations explicit, and by convention, only constructor functions should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @thesystem I see! I did have that incorrect then.  thanks for pointing it out.  I'll edit the answer